# CakePHP 3.x : transform updateAll() into save() loop, for a multiple edit page

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I use audit-stash plugin which works fine with all my tables. But I have a particular function in which the user selects rows with checkboxes, and then changes a specific field to all of them. The table audits contains a fields called "primary_key" which seems not working for such case.

in my Controller, function, I put this:

```
$this->request->data;
$data = $this->request->data;
if($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) 
{
    $ids = $this->request->data('data.AssetsAssignations.id');
    $room_id = $this->request->data('room_id');

    $this->AssetsAssignations->updateAll(
        ['room_id ' => $room_id ],
        ['id IN' => $ids]
    );

}
```

in my table, I used this:

```
$this->addBehavior('AuditStash.AuditLog');
```

I was told that there is no way around this for audit-stash, because updateAll bypasses model callbacks by directly sending a query to the database.

I was suggested to update records one by one if I need to keep the log.

How can I transform my updateAll() code into a Save() loop ?

This try did not work for me, using save() and saveMany() :

```
$this->request->data;
    $data = $this->request->data;

    if($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) 
    {
        $ids = $this->request->data('data.AssetsAssignations.id');
        $asset_status_id = $this->request->data('asset_status_id');
        foreach($ids as $id) {
            $this->AssetsAssignations->saveMany(
                ['asset_status_id ' => $asset_status_id ]
            );

        }
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: So, for each id, you'll need to get the entity, patch it, and then save? What code have you tried along these lines?

Comment: I updated my question. I tried 
            $ids = $this->request->data('data.AssetsAssignations.id');
            $asset_status_id = $this->request->data('asset_status_id');
            foreach($ids as $id) {
                $this->AssetsAssignations->saveMany(
                    ['asset_status_id ' => $asset_status_id ]
                );
                
            }
        }

Comment: `save` and `saveMany` both take entities as parameters; the former takes one, the latter takes an array. You'll need to either `get`, update and `save` each entity one at a time in your `foreach` loop, or else `find` all of them (with `->where(['id IN' => $ids])`), loop over that set to update each one, and then `saveMany`. If there are a lot of such records, the former could be better for memory usage; if a fairly small number, the latter might be a bit faster.

Comment: thanks alot @Greg. It worked:
`            $ids = $this->request->data('data.AssetsAssignations.id');
            $asset_status_id = $this->request->data('asset_status_id');
            $assetsAssignationsTable = TableRegistry::get('AssetsAssignations');
            foreach($ids as $id) {
                $assetsAssignation = $assetsAssignationsTable->get($id); // Return assetsAssignation with id 
                $assetsAssignation->asset_status_id = $asset_status_id;
                $assetsAssignationsTable->save($assetsAssignation);
            }
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't have to call `get($id)` for every id. This get the entity from the table and causes a lot of useless queries

```
if($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) 
{
    $ids = $this->request->data('data.AssetsAssignations.id');
    $asset_status_id = $this->request->data('asset_status_id');
    $assetsAssignationsTable = TableRegistry::get('AssetsAssignations');
    foreach($ids as $id) {
        $assetsAssignation = $assetsAssignationsTable->newEntity(); // returns an empty entity
        $assetsAssignation->id = $id; // assign the id to the entity
        $assetsAssignation->asset_status_id = $asset_status_id;
        $assetsAssignationsTable->save($assetsAssignation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat technique. No need to unset the `isNew`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Greg, this code worked for me:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
...
if($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) 
    {
        $ids = $this->request->data('data.AssetsAssignations.id');
        $asset_status_id = $this->request->data('asset_status_id');
        $assetsAssignationsTable = TableRegistry::get('AssetsAssignations');
        foreach($ids as $id) {
            $assetsAssignation = $assetsAssignationsTable->get($id); // Return assetsAssignation with id 
            $assetsAssignation->asset_status_id = $asset_status_id;
            $assetsAssignationsTable->save($assetsAssignation);
        }
    }
```